# Javascript, creating and listening to a custom event

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble creating and listening to a custom event I have created in javascript. I think I am missing something small here, but I am not sure what. Here is the code :

```
document.body.addEventListener('launch', onLaunch);
function onLaunch(item) {
    console.log("laucnhed with", item);
}
function launch(id) {
    console.log("launch", id);
    const event = new CustomEvent("launch", {activity: id});

    document.body.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

So the first log "launch", and the id shows up correctly, however the second one in the onLaunch function fires correctly, however the item has no detail - logging item.detail is null. What needs to be done to correctly pass that activity property to the listener function? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs at the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent):

> CustomEvent.detail
>   Any data passed when initializing the event.

You need to wrap your event details like this:

```
const event = new CustomEvent("launch", { detail: { activity: id } });
```

Then you could change your logging in the event listener to:

```
console.log("launched with", item.detail.activity);
```

A more detailed example of the CustomEvent contructor can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent#Example).